# Removing defalt background on item selection in Telerik RadListView for UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, telerik

I am using the Telerik RadListView Control in my UWP application. I want to remove the default selection background provided by the RadlistView which is shown in green in the [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkQGa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Telerik for UWP is now open source. You could see its all code from GitHub: https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP

For your question, if you debug your project in visual studio and check its visual tree, you would see that it actually is a Grid control named as 'CheckBox'.

[image]

So, what we need to do is finding the style of RadListViewItem and change the 'CheckBackground[Path]' fill color when it's selected.

Then, the style of RadListViewItem also could be found on github:https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP/blob/master/Controls/DataControls/DataControls.UWP/Themes/Generic.xaml#L705

You could copy it and apply it for your own project. To achieve your requirement, you just need to change the 'Selected' visual state in this style.

I made a code sample for your reference:

`xmlns:telerikDataControls="using:Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Data"`
`xmlns:listView="using:Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Data.ListView"`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TelerikSecondaryForegroundBrush" Color="#99FFFFFF" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TelerikSelectedBrush" Color="#FF006AC1" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TelerikHighlightBrush" Color="#FF006AC1" />
        <Style TargetType="listView:RadListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="55" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="55" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="listView:RadListViewItem">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding DisabledStateOpacity, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectedState">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderState">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ReorderEnabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ReorderHandle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ReorderDisabled" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="PART_Content" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                        IsTabStop="False" />
                                <Border x:Name="border"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{x:Null}" />
                                <Grid x:Name="CheckBox" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="35" Height="35" Margin="4"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                    <Path x:Name="CheckBackground"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Stretch="Fill"
                                Fill="{StaticResource TelerikSelectedBrush}"
                                Data="M0,0 L86.1743,0 L86.1743,86.1743 z"
                                StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeThickness="0">
                                    </Path>
                                    <Path x:Name="CheckMark"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Stretch="Fill"
                                Fill="White" Margin="16,0,0,17"
                                Data="M0,119 L31,92 L119,185 L267,0 L300,24 L122,250 z"
                                StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeThickness="0" />
                                </Grid>
                                <Border Background="Transparent"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Path=Orientation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                              Converter={StaticResource orientationToHorizontalAlignmentConverter},
                                                              ConverterParameter=First}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{Binding Path=Orientation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                              Converter={StaticResource orientationToVerticalAlignmentConverter},
                                                              ConverterParameter=First}"
                                Height="{Binding Path=Orientation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                 Converter={StaticResource orientationToSizeConverter},
                                                 ConverterParameter=Height}"
                                Width="{Binding Path=Orientation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                 Converter={StaticResource orientationToSizeConverter},
                                                 ConverterParameter=Width}"
                                x:Name="PART_FirstHandle" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" />
                                <Border Background="Transparent"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Path=Orientation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                              Converter={StaticResource orientationToHorizontalAlignmentConverter},
                                                              ConverterParameter=Second}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{Binding Path=Orientation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                              Converter={StaticResource orientationToVerticalAlignmentConverter},
                                                              ConverterParameter=Second}"
                                Height="{Binding Path=Orientation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                 Converter={StaticResource orientationToSizeConverter},
                                                 ConverterParameter=Height}"
                                Width="{Binding Path=Orientation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                 Converter={StaticResource orientationToSizeConverter},
                                                 ConverterParameter=Width}"
                                x:Name="PART_SecondHandle" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" />
                                <BitmapIcon x:Name="PART_ReorderHandle" UriSource="{Binding HandleIconPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                    ManipulationMode="None" Width="48" Height="48"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy">
                                    <BitmapIcon.RenderTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="{Binding Orientation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource orientationToRotateDegreesConverter}}" />
                                    </BitmapIcon.RenderTransform>
                                </BitmapIcon>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <telerikDataControls:RadListView x:Name="listView">
    </telerikDataControls:RadListView>
</Grid>
```

[image]